# Side by side output from two `tail -f` commands

Tags: tail, paste

I have two scripts emitting single string to log files periodically that I need to `tail -f` and combine side by side for which I am using `paste`. This works but I am unable to pipe the output to another `tail -f` so that I can get a continuous output of the two strings pasted side by side.

To illustrate / reproduce the problem, I have the following scripts:

p1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while true
do
  i=$((i+1))
  sleep 4
  echo "P1string$i" >> out1.log
done
```

p2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while true
do
  i=$((i+1))
  sleep 4
  echo "P2string$i" >> out2.log
done
```

I run them in the background like so:

```
$ ./p1.sh &
$ ./p2.sh &
```

Now, this works:

```
paste <(tail -f out1.log) <(tail -f out2.log)
```

But this does not work:

```
paste <(tail -f out1.log) <(tail -f out2.log) | tail -f
```

In principle, this is just piping stdout to `tail -f` and should work! no?

Comment: Why would you need another `tail -f`? The command you posted, `paste <(tail -f out1.log) <(tail -f out2.log)` does already exactly what you want. The problem I see in this approach is only, if one logfile is growing faster than the other, as paste will wait for a new line from each file.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) (packaged on Debian and derivatives at least).

Comment: @treuss, I am using tail -f after pipe as an example that I need the side by side lines from the two log files send over a pipe for immediate processing. I should perhaps be using some other command for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "In principle, this is just piping stdout to tail -f and should work! no?", the answer is indeed "no".

The `tail` command is meant to give the last 10 lines of output of a file or stdin. Used on a pipe, it will wait for the pipe to be closed to then print out the last 10 lines it has buffered. In your example, the pipe is never closed, so tail will never print out anything.

A simple test to prove this is `while true; do echo "Hello"; done | tail -f`, which will also never print anything.

Comment:  note that at least with GNU `tail`, piping to `tail -n +1 -f` would work (though you'd likely also need to disable buffering in `paste`), but would serve no purpose. POSIX says `-f` is to be ignored if used on stdin and stdin is a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have them side by side ... try

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt > merged.txt
```

or if you want them delimited

```
paste -d ',' file1.txt file2.txt > merged.txt
```

Comment: I am looking to have the two log files' output side by side *live* ie while they are being written into the files so that I can immediately pipe them to another program to process them. The log process is continuous so I can't wait for it to finish.